# (asp.net MVC5) change background color of a tables based on what a method called profibility returns

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-mvc-5

hey i have this view in my mvc application. If you look at the "tr" where it says "lönsamhet: " and then a method is executed which counts and returns the profilbility of the project. and if the profibility method returns a number bigger than 20% i want the table background color to turn green. and if less than 20% i want it to turn red... How can i do that? and my model is a list of a object i made called project. css is not my best side so would appricieate help. thanks.

```
@model  List<Blogg.Models.BlogPost>
@foreach (var item in Model)
```

{

```
 <div>
        <table style="font-family: Arial; border:1px solid black; width: 1000px; height: 20px">

        <tr>
              <td><b>Projekt Numer: </b>@item.ID</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><b>Projekt Namn: </b>@item.name</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Kund Namn: </b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><b>Lönsamhet: </b>@item.profitability()</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td><b>@ViewBag.Basecamp</b></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.ActionLink("Detaljer", "Details", new { id = item.ID })</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: 20% of what ..? What does `profitability()` method returns ? a decimal value ?

Comment: Use a view model with a property (say) `string ClassName` and set sits value in the controller and then use `<tr class=@item.ClassName">`

Comment: profitability() returns double

Answer (score 0):

Could you not use JQuery?

```
<td class="profit"><b>Lönsamhet: </b>@item.profitability()</td>

if(variableName > 20){
    $('.profit').css("background-color","green");
}
else{
    $('.profit').css("background-color","red");
}
```

For multiple fields do a jquery.each loop and grab the value of each class.

```
$('.profit').each(function(){
    var variableName = $(this).val();
    if(variableName > 20){
        $('.profit').css("background-color","green");
    }
    else{
        $('.profit').css("background-color","red");
    }
});
```